# Error in compiling SCSS in Bootstrap 5.1.3 Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to update a working web site to bootstrap 5.1.3.    This time around I would like to have the styles handled by Sass, and modify them myself somewhat.  I have copied the .scss files to my _sass folder and when i make a change it's updating the .css file as it should.   However I'm getting an error message and i can't see what's the matter with the code.   (It's reporting an error in the files I downloaded from bootstrap that haven't been touched).    Here's the error - I can't beleve that the bootstrap crew have allowed this error in their code, so i must surely have made some blunder in my setup.      Can anyone see what this error means and where i ought to go looking for the cure?

```
    "Invalid CSS after "...ass}: #{$value}": expected "{", was ";"
on line 55 of D:/Sites/Mysites/FoggyHollow/www/_scss/mixins/_utilities.scss
from line 21 of D:/Sites/Mysites/FoggyHollow/www/_scss/_mixins.scss
from line 12 of D:/Sites/Mysites/FoggyHollow/www/_scss/bootstrap.scss

50:         /* rtl:begin:remove */
51:       }
52: 
53:       @if $is-css-var {
54:         .#{$property-class + $infix + $property-class-modifier} {
55:           --#{$variable-prefix}#{$property-class}: #{$value};
56:         }
57:
58:         @each $pseudo in $state {
59:           .#{$property-class + $infix + $property-class-modifier}-#{$pseudo}:#{$pseudo} {
60:             --#{$variable-prefix}#{$property-class}: #{$value};"; }
```

Cheers
Mike Kear
Windsor,  NSW,  Australia

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure.   The one that comes with Adobe Dreamweaver 2022  I'm not sure i can be more specific for you

Comment: I don't know anything about Dreamweaver but maybe it doesn't support the latest version of sass.

Comment: If you can, try to use another compiler than what's native to Dreamweaver. See the answer of Birnou on [this post](https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver-discussions/dart-sass%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C%E3%82%92%E5%B8%8C%E6%9C%9B%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/m-p/12785844).

Comment: Thank you Arkellys,   I  did that and found that i dont have to do much more than i was doing already,   except it's not as sweet as having it all built-in to the tool I'm using for writing the code.   I'm now using Dart-sass thanks to your suggestion.      And I also realise there are some updates to CSS that i need to learn about so I'm doing an online course on CSS to bring myself up to date.     Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. :)

Comment: May I suggest you answer your own question with what you have done to fix the problem? It may be useful for other people in the future.